# Scoring in jQuery draggables

Tags: c#, jquery, scoring

I am working on a game which is on jQuery and I am new to it. I was wondering how it is possible to store this games scores in some variable and then in some variable in c# so I could make the SQL connection and send it to db table. I don't know if its possible but I want it to work something like that. Don't know how to use ajax call and stuff. It would be easier for me to work if it gets linked to c# somehow. 
I am working on asp.net webforms.

Help me with the scoring thing, Please! I so want to do it and I kind of don't have much time. Thankss.

Here is the code,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Img6').hide();
            $('#Img7').hide();
            $(function () {
            $("#draggable").draggable({ revert: "invalid", helper: 'clone', tolerance: 'fit' });
            $("#draggable1").draggable({ revert: "invalid", helper: 'clone', tolerance: 'fit' });
            $("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: "invalid", helper: 'clone', tolerance: 'fit' });
            $("#droppable").droppable({

                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var TestOp = $(this).attr('id');
                    if (TestOp == "droppable") {
                        $("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
                        $("#draggable1").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
                        $("#draggable").draggable({ revert: "valid" });

                        $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("> p")
        .html("Dropped!");
                        return true;
                    }

                    else {
                        $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("> p")
        .html("Wolaaa");
                    }
                }
            });
        });


        $(".arrow").click(function () {
            $('#Img1').hide();
            $('#Img6').show();

            $(function () {
                $("#draggable").draggable({ revert: "valid", helper: 'clone' });
                $("#draggable1").draggable({ revert: "valid", helper: 'clone' });
                $("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: "valid", helper: 'clone' });

                //            $(".draggable,.draggable1,.draggable2").draggable('refresh');
                $("#droppable").droppable({
                    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        var TestOp = $(this).attr('id');
                        if (TestOp == "droppable") {
                            $("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: "valid" });

                            $("#draggable1").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
                            $("#draggable").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

                            $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("> p")
        .html("Dropped!");
                            return true;
                        }

                        else {
                            $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("> p")
        .html("Wolaaa");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        });
        $(".arrow").dblclick(function () {
            $('#Img7').show();
            $('#Img6').hide();
            $('#Img1').hide();
            $(function () {
                $("#draggable").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
                $("#draggable1").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
                $("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
                $("#droppable").droppable({
                    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        var TestOp = $(this).attr('id');
                        if (TestOp == "droppable") {
                            $("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
                            $("#draggable1").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
                            $("#draggable").draggable({ revert: "valid" });

                            $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("> p")
        .html("Dropped!");
                            return true;
                        }

                        else {
                            $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("> p")
        .html("Wolaaa");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        $(".leftarrow").click(function () {
            $('#Img1').show();
            $('#Img6').hide();
            $('#Img7').hide();
        });
    });

    $('#submitScore').on('click', function (e) {

    $.post( 'example.aspx', { userScore: '100', userId: '2' })
    .done(function (data) {

    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using HTML local storage for storing scores. This will allow a persistance of scores between sessions as well.

You can read up about local storage here: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

If you want to get the value back to C# aswell/instead, then you can simply do this via a normal Ajax call. Assuming you are using MVC and Web API, then set up a route if different from default;

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ScoreApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then create a Web Api Controller (or normal controller if you really want to, but you need an standard MVC route as well);

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string score)
    {
        ////DO SOMETHING WITH SCORE

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
        response.Content = new StringContent("Score Saved", Encoding.Unicode);
        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
        MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
        };

        return response;
    }
```

Now finally just call from within your drop function;

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/SaveScore" + score,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                alert(Data);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I am working on the asp webforms.. Can you suggest what i can do in asp webforms?

Comment: With regards to local storage then this obviously stays the same in webforms. You can also still use the Web API with a Web Forms project (which is what I would recommend). Check this link: [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms)

Comment: I have to add the route code to Application_Start, right?
It is giving error on the config..

Comment: Yes routes should be on Application_Start. Have you got the correct .Net version and API references? You may need to open a seperate question for this.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't know if it has something to do with the API references and .Net version. Version is 4.5.

Comment: Suggest you open a new question for resolving your issue with using Web Api in WebForms project. I believe the original question is answered.